# Pyboof: How to use python wrappers in java?

Tags: java, python, wrapper

I have downloaded pyboof which are python wrappers in java. So, my question is how exactly can I use them? I wrote a simple program that opens a command shell and runs the wrapper from there. My program is the above:

```
package alltestshere;

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.* ;

import boofcv.io.UtilIO;
import boofcv.io.image.UtilImageIO;

public class PythonCaller {

    public static void main (String [] args) throws IOException {



        Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
        Process pr = rt.exec("cmd set PATH = C:\\Python27");
        Process pr2 = rt.exec("cmd python27 C:\\Users\\Caterina\\Downloads\\PyBoof-master\\PyBoof-master\\examples\\blur_image.py");
        Process pr3 = rt.exec("cmd blur_image.py");


        }
  }
```

But when I run it nothing happens. I try to run the "blur_image" py file in python shell as well but it just opens the file while I want to see how the picture has changed (the new picture). So, is this a wrong way to use python wrappers or do I have to do something more in order to use the wrappers? The blur_image wrapper can be found here https://github.com/lessthanoptimal/PyBoof/blob/master/examples/blur_image.py.

Comment: According to their documentation _"PyBoof is Python wrapper for the computer vision library BoofCV. Since this is a Java library you will need to have java and javac installed."_ In other words, you are trying to call a Python wrapper around a Java library from Java. Why?! Just use that BoofCV library directly as that is a Java library.

Comment: Ok,thank you very much!! Seems that got something wrong!

Answer (score 0):

Script to run python from Java could look like following:

```java
String script = "C:\\Users\\Caterina\\Downloads\\PyBoof-master\\PyBoof-master\\examples\\blur_image.py";
String python_app = "python27"
Process pr = rt.exec(new String[]{python_app, script})
```

After process run, you need to wait when it finish by doing following:

```java
pr.waitFor()
```

If script is expected will write some output or read some input, you should 
read output and write something for it's input.

Following example writes something to the input stream of subprocess:

```java
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
    new OutputStreamWriter(p.getOutputStream()));

writer.write("something");
writer.newLine();
writer.close();
```

Nevertheless, `PyBoof` is a *Python* wrapper for the computer vision library `BoofCV` (opposite direction, from Python to call Java) as it written on it's GitHub page and you can use BoofCV library directly from Java.

Comment: The OP shouldn't use this library at all. But if you execute something like this, you also need to consume the error and output stream of that process, otherwise the process might block.

Comment: Ok thank you! I am now having a process=2 error (system cannot find the file specified) and am working on that. In any case, I am just trying to figure out how to use Java and Python at the same time, that's why I tried that.

Comment: @KaterinaKornilia Nice! you may aslo output environment that Java knows. I prefer to tweak System environment first by adding Python and Python scripts folder.

Comment: Additionally, you may try to look on [jPype](https://github.com/jpype-project/jpype) project which interconnects Java and Python in more seamless way.

Comment: Thank you @Eir Nym! I can not use jPype, I am trying to install it through pip in Python 2.7.15 and there is no matching distribution found.

Comment: @KaterinaKornilia Indeed, there's a build for Python3 in PyPI (named JPype1-py3). May I ask why do you have to use Python2 in 2018?

Comment: Because I firstly tried Jython, which is not compatible with Python 3.x. Since I am working with two PCs I will try it on the other one, in which I have Python 3.6 installed and tell you.

Comment: I tried it through Anaconda3 and did not work either appearing the same message "No matching distribution found for jpype"

Comment: Updated my answer with better process handling